# constants for LaTeX

Tags: c#, latex

I am working on a C# port of LaTeX, based on [iosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath). One thing I can't figure out is where they get their constants from, that they use for spacing, italic corrections, etc. I'm hoping an iosMath author is on here and can help out?

For example, see [this plist file](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/1dee822d35ae6412cffadfd855151908c0d83c8b/fonts/latinmodern-math.plist). All those constants had to come from somewhere. But where?

Comment: The constants probably point to elements within the font. While each element has a name, they can also be represented by a position within the font. Just a guess...

Comment: Why don't ask this at `tex.stackexchange.com`? There are many TeX experts there.

Comment: They come from the font (i.e. are part of the font, as designed by the font designer). In this case (going by the filename) they come from the Latin Modern font, which is based on Computer Modern, which was designed by Donald Knuth with feedback from many typography experts. (If you want to go further back, it in turn was based originally on Monotype Modern 8A (and others), which was a font designed for hot-metal typesetting around 1900 I think.)